# Filling array on event and access it outside the event function handler

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, events, dom-events

I'm trying to fill an array on an event (onclick) with the button's value (there will be different buttons with different values, that's why I'm using an array), and I want to be able to access that array outside the event handler function. 
This is what I tried so far, but I just can't figure how to access the array outside the event handler function.

Here's the HTML:

```
<button value="5"> button </button>
<div> The value is: <span id="res"></span></div>
```

And here the script:

```
var n = [];
var val;
var ret;

function add(arr,val) {
arr.push(val); 
return val;
} 
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        val = event.target.value;
        ret = add(n, val); 
        console.log(n);      //these console.log are tests
        console.log(ret);
    } 
 console.log(ret);    //also this
});

//need to access the array here
console.log(n);    //obv doesn't work
console.log(ret);  //same

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = ret;  //it remains undefined, obv
```

I know why this doesn't work (it's because I do all the thing inside the event handler function), but I can't figure it out how to do what I want to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you use a function to add to an array? It _is_ already a function... Just replace `ret = add(n, val); ` with `n.push(val)` and you should have no problems.

Comment: It's just a try to store the value to reuse it in another part of the code, because this is what i need to do.
Just replacing doesn't work, the user dsh explained why.

Comment: jup, I missed that but dsh got a nice upvote for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the action you want to perform in the callback, not before.  The reason is that none of the code in the event handler runs before the event occurs.  Just declaring the variable doesn't change the order of execution.
So you need to put

```
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = ret;
```

inside your event handler function.

Updated (and simplified) code:

```
var n = [];

document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        var val = event.target.value;
        n.push(val);
        console.log(n);      //these console.log are tests
        console.log(ret);
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = val;
    }
});
```

Comment: The fact is that this doesn't solve my problem. With this solution i can see in the div the content of the array. But i need to use the array outside the event handler function,in other parts of the code, to do other actions, like passing it to another function, extract values, etc.

Comment: You can use it outside the function, and pass it to functions and so on.  What you can't do is get the value of an event that hasn't happened yet!  You need, then, to have your event handler call some function to make more things happen _after_ the click event. So fill in some more of your code if you need more guidance on designing event-driven/asynchronous code.

Comment: Ok @dsh, i get it. It's all about make things happen **after** the click event happened. Thank you.